# Vendor.Js is not creating while gulp build in yeomen generator project

Tags: angularjs, gulp, yeoman-generator

I have created a angular with es6 project using yeomen gulp-angular generator.

But after gulp build vendor js file is not generating in the scripts folder.

build file is

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});

gulp.task('partials', function () {
 return gulp.src([
 path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'),
path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.html')
])
.pipe($.htmlmin({
  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
  removeAttributeQuotes: true,
  collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
  collapseWhitespace: true
}))
.pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
  module: 'sfxChat',
  root: 'app'
}))
   .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.tmp + '/partials/'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
  var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
  var partialsInjectOptions = {
starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
addRootSlash: false
};

var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', { restore: true });
var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', { restore: true });

return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
.pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
.pipe($.useref())
.pipe(jsFilter)
.pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
.pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
.pipe($.rev())
.pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
.pipe(jsFilter.restore)
.pipe(cssFilter)
// .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
.pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/material-design-iconfont/iconfont/', '../fonts/'))
.pipe($.cssnano())
.pipe($.rev())
// .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
.pipe(cssFilter.restore)
.pipe($.revReplace())
.pipe(htmlFilter)
.pipe($.htmlmin({
  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
  removeAttributeQuotes: true,
  collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
  collapseWhitespace: true
}))
.pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
.pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
.pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true     }));
});

// Only applies for fonts from bower dependencies
// Custom fonts are handled by the "other" task
gulp.task('fonts', function () {
return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles().concat('bower_components/material-design-iconfont/iconfont/*'))
.pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,otf,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
.pipe($.flatten())
.pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/fonts/')));
});

gulp.task('other', function () {
var fileFilter = $.filter(function (file) {
return file.stat.isFile();
});

return gulp.src([
path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/*'),
path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/**/*.{html,css,js,scss}')
])
.pipe(fileFilter)
.pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')));
  });

 gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return $.del([path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'),      path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/')]);
 });

 gulp.task('build', ['html', 'fonts', 'other']);
```

While gulp serve everything is working but in gulp build vendor js file is not generating